# Error: Could not locate a Flask application

Tags: flask

> Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

I am facing this error for `flask run`.

Comment: Plaese refer these 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119495/how-to-setup-environment-variables-for-flask-run-on-windows

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/1881

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask says "did not provide the FLASK\_APP environment variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620674/flask-says-did-not-provide-the-flask-app-environment-variable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826016/env-variables-not-set-while-running-minimal-flask-application

Comment: This will fix it [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826016/env-variables-not-set-while-running-minimal-flask-application)

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue, setting environment variable using

```
 $env:FLASK_APP="base.py"
```

then

```
flask run
```

This worked for me. This works for `flask db init` also

Answer (score 11):

Before executing `flask run`, you need to specify the flask application file by executing

```
export FLASK_APP=[YOUR_APP_FILE].py
```

(Note: make sure your application file is in the root directory)

You can create a file named **`.flaskenv`** in your project root directory so you don't have to type in the above command every time to run your application - flask would automatically look for this file.

Quote from docs:

> If python-dotenv is installed, running the flask command will set environment variables defined in the files .env and .flaskenv. This can be used to avoid having to set FLASK_APP manually every time you open a new terminal, and to set configuration using environment variables similar to how some deployment services work.

1. If you haven't installed `python-dotenv`, run `pip install python-dotenv`
2. Create your .flaskenv file in the root directory and populate it with:

```
FLASK_APP=[YOUR_APP_FILE].py
```

After that you can safely execute `flask run`

Comment: or just run python your_python_file.py

Answer (score 9):

For pycharm windows run these line on the terminal:

- set FLASK_APP=main.py
- $env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"
- flask run

This works for me.

Comment: thanks i was missing the $env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"

Answer (score 4):

For individuals using powershell:
Copy below into your terminal:

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "hello.py"
```

Then run:

```
 flask run
```

Answer (score 1):

In general this means flask can't find your flask app. This happens when, as the error message indicates, the environment doesn't contain information about `FLASK_APP` (e.g. FLASK_APP="website" for website.py). You can either fix this by setting the environment variable or by using python directly.

For the environment variable could approach this with (for website.py): `FLASK_APP="website" flask run`. For windows see the comment by Sync.

When using python you should rely on `__name__` and app.run() for a development server. After adding the bottom part you may be able to call the script directly with `python3`:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

> the `if` clause ensure that `app.run()` is only called when executing the script directly and not when importing `app` from e.g. another script.

NOTE: It's hard to help you without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

All suggestions above didn't work for me I added the lines below and worked perfectly:

if **name** == "**main**":
app.run()

Answer (score 1):

i Just run

**flask --app hello run**

in terminal and it worked.
where hello is the name of file without the .py extension

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue...
I typed in the terminal next:

```
$env:FLASK_APP="YOUR FULL PATH to the  file"
```

like this:

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "C:\Users\M...\D...\project...\hello_f\hello.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, stumbled upon this solution on Flask documentation:

$env:FLASK_APP = "hello.py"  instead of "set FLASK_APP=hello.py", that is if your terminal is Windows Powershell.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the main.py file into app.py and then run

`$ flask db init`